# Byte Array to NSData

Tags: arrays, objective-c, nsdata

In a WebService JSON response is coming. In the response, there is image is coming as a byte array. I have to show the image in a UIImageView. I am trying to convert the byte array to NSData. But not getting how to do that. Any help would be appreciated.
I am confident that the byte array has image data in it.
Sample Byte array for your reference:

```c
unsigned char array = {
            137,
            80,
            78,
            71,
            ...
            66,
            96,
            130
};
```

Thanks

Comment: I would recommend not to add such lengthy coding which is not needed in your question ...

Comment: This is not JSON. Or are these squared brackets instead of parnetheses?

Comment: Where do you have this array? Is it a C style array?

Comment: @BrunoFerreira no, he gets this as a JSON text array

Comment: @H2CO3 I think that is an `NSLog()` output. And `NSLog()` prints `NSArray`s with `()` and not `[]`.

Comment: @HAS I didn't insist this wasn't `NSLog()` output - all I wrote was "This is not JSON". And it isn't.

Comment: @H2CO3 you are right, I misread that, sorry ;)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You have to convert the JSON to an array of strings first; you can, for example, use the [`NSJSONSerialization` class](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

```
NSArray *strings = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:theJSONString options:kNilOptions error:NULL];
```

Then walk the strings array, convert each entry to an integer, and add it to an allocated byte pointer/array:

```
unsigned c = strings.count;
uint8_t *bytes = malloc(sizeof(*bytes) * c);

unsigned i;
for (i = 0; i < c; i++)
{
    NSString *str = [strings objectAtIndex:i];
    int byte = [str intValue];
    bytes[i] = byte;
}
```

Then finally make an NSData out of the bytes, then init an UIImage object using it:

```
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:bytes length:c freeWhenDone:YES];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
```

Comment: Note that you are getting NSNumber objects not NSStrings from JSON like that. But since both respond to the intValue message your code still works. Would be better to write NSNumber or maybe even id though.

Comment: what is theJSONString? the method takes nsdata and not nsstring.. how come this works?

Comment: How to get NSArray *strings if JSON response is not received? I get NSArray *strings nil.

Comment: Setting freeWhenDone to YES caused my app to crash  with malloc: *** error but stopped when I changed it to NO

Answer (score 42):

Here is an example of getting your data into a NSData object.

```
const unsigned char bytes[] = {values here};
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:bytes length:sizeof(bytes)];
NSLog(@"%@", data);
```

Comment: this answers only the very last part of the question.

Answer (score 3):

and here's how to do it in Swift...

```
var bytes:[Byte] = [137, 80, 78, 71, 13, 10, 26, 10, 0, 0, 0, 13, 73, 72, 68, 82, 0, 0, 0, 130, 0, 0, 0, 22, 8, 6, 0, 0, 0, 12, 244, 68, 168, 0, 0, 0, 1, 115, 82, 71, 66, 0, 174, 206, 28, 233, 0, 0, 0, 4, 103, 65, 77, 65, 0, 0, 177, 143, 11, 252, 97, 5, 0, 0, 0, 9, 112, 72, 89, 115, 0, 0, 14, 196, 0, 0, 14, 196, 1, 149, 43, 14, 27, 0, 0, 3, 212, 73, 68, 65, 84, 104, 67, 237, 153, 61, 139, 20, 65, 16, 134, 55, 17, 253, 3, 114, 127, 224, 208, 204, 64, 228, 18, 3, 19, 21, 19, 35, 217, 200, 204, 15, 48, 19, 228, 48, 50, 242, 76, 12, 245, 2, 99, 47, 55, 88, 83, 65, 220, 76, 48, 57, 19, 49, 220, 95, 224, 125, 120, 34, 126, 224, 120, 207, 65, 141, 53, 189, 213, 85, 189, 238, 172, 176, 210, 5, 195, 206, 77, 87, 87, 247, 84, 189, 245, 118, 213, 220, 160, 169, 82, 61, 112, 232, 129, 65, 245, 66, 245, 0, 30, 168, 64, 168, 56, 56, 242, 64, 5, 66, 5, 66, 5, 66, 197, 192, 31, 15, 12, 142, 29, 63, 209, 228, 174, 209, 232, 101, 199, 87, 147, 201, 36, 171, 139, 141, 55, 227, 113, 179, 122, 234, 180, 171, 115, 110, 109, 173, 217, 217, 217, 53, 99, 112, 241, 210, 229, 169, 185, 216, 244, 246, 88, 50, 134, 93, 145, 18, 125, 79, 231, 230, 173, 219, 217, 253, 47, 51, 176, 92, 32, 156, 92, 89, 233, 188, 219, 189, 245, 245, 16, 8, 219, 219, 239, 27, 230, 69, 206, 76, 157, 246, 112, 99, 99, 106, 14, 78, 71, 230, 13, 94, 159, 64, 96, 47, 218, 222, 50, 7, 95, 239, 221, 5, 2, 47, 77, 96, 17, 178, 56, 10, 48, 217, 139, 192, 36, 81, 240, 158, 111, 109, 181, 251, 176, 178, 30, 102, 233, 43, 139, 75, 128, 192, 187, 161, 39, 87, 196, 108, 226, 23, 15, 8, 223, 70, 47, 154, 131, 7, 247, 155, 253, 27, 215, 155, 79, 103, 86, 59, 23, 207, 24, 67, 71, 203, 175, 253, 189, 230, 235, 179, 39, 157, 235, 199, 187, 183, 13, 23, 250, 123, 195, 171, 71, 118, 248, 229, 111, 158, 91, 130, 221, 207, 119, 239, 52, 59, 231, 207, 154, 107, 179, 6, 107, 137, 132, 64, 128, 202, 145, 167, 155, 155, 97, 112, 5, 8, 232, 91, 25, 174, 193, 129, 227, 113, 38, 0, 179, 156, 206, 49, 84, 2, 132, 89, 51, 50, 7, 208, 52, 203, 217, 151, 7, 102, 253, 174, 233, 30, 126, 126, 252, 208, 6, 44, 5, 128, 245, 55, 65, 101, 14, 66, 96, 83, 29, 43, 152, 90, 231, 251, 235, 87, 237, 22, 176, 19, 233, 235, 185, 2, 196, 16, 8, 165, 103, 191, 232, 105, 167, 64, 237, 158, 51, 1, 217, 181, 225, 112, 74, 7, 16, 105, 241, 108, 244, 5, 4, 246, 66, 112, 229, 138, 128, 239, 49, 130, 100, 109, 9, 8, 68, 103, 247, 202, 133, 44, 16, 34, 59, 4, 94, 196, 2, 1, 207, 96, 32, 139, 153, 176, 13, 248, 90, 32, 224, 136, 156, 195, 117, 198, 122, 122, 105, 150, 144, 85, 158, 190, 181, 158, 117, 254, 70, 199, 140, 55, 158, 218, 155, 199, 150, 204, 245, 106, 4, 178, 211, 10, 28, 52, 205, 24, 23, 247, 150, 14, 99, 22, 35, 136, 46, 129, 204, 101, 59, 64, 128, 238, 83, 187, 28, 31, 233, 209, 147, 234, 0, 220, 22, 8, 81, 6, 136, 19, 60, 61, 139, 46, 75, 106, 11, 177, 205, 113, 97, 117, 20, 243, 4, 175, 111, 32, 68, 93, 131, 21, 12, 28, 157, 138, 197, 26, 204, 205, 29, 13, 114, 116, 96, 199, 2, 3, 243, 172, 140, 103, 29, 97, 3, 126, 249, 219, 154, 223, 2, 129, 5, 162, 2, 73, 186, 136, 92, 96, 114, 231, 38, 52, 90, 18, 204, 180, 93, 45, 169, 17, 116, 129, 103, 221, 75, 231, 81, 98, 43, 98, 22, 93, 183, 228, 142, 36, 11, 8, 60, 75, 37, 167, 103, 1, 1, 6, 209, 98, 129, 136, 121, 127, 115, 36, 9, 59, 116, 128, 16, 177, 130, 156, 221, 179, 2, 129, 151, 136, 90, 79, 198, 115, 242, 47, 106, 4, 214, 240, 186, 34, 41, 110, 163, 154, 164, 132, 158, 177, 1, 101, 167, 20, 157, 99, 132, 20, 72, 86, 230, 151, 50, 130, 102, 7, 125, 223, 1, 66, 196, 10, 146, 17, 139, 0, 66, 238, 35, 19, 123, 138, 170, 119, 93, 228, 165, 247, 227, 195, 2, 80, 23, 118, 158, 173, 40, 17, 116, 75, 59, 11, 35, 16, 112, 221, 38, 114, 111, 213, 8, 60, 183, 24, 161, 20, 8, 95, 30, 63, 10, 107, 4, 169, 37, 210, 22, 117, 10, 8, 57, 103, 80, 221, 71, 244, 234, 181, 84, 81, 59, 233, 101, 90, 201, 177, 18, 209, 122, 180, 119, 230, 35, 81, 167, 83, 242, 49, 105, 150, 246, 77, 3, 130, 190, 126, 30, 32, 48, 223, 90, 155, 35, 3, 144, 88, 44, 196, 250, 204, 153, 2, 2, 206, 176, 40, 178, 36, 171, 254, 7, 32, 148, 116, 58, 105, 123, 155, 130, 56, 151, 241, 94, 27, 40, 140, 49, 15, 16, 216, 199, 172, 107, 3, 2, 10, 209, 129, 20, 88, 250, 101, 96, 5, 93, 120, 105, 54, 64, 79, 198, 104, 13, 245, 189, 215, 91, 243, 37, 49, 87, 216, 201, 71, 171, 28, 43, 48, 47, 93, 43, 183, 7, 235, 185, 174, 63, 188, 226, 82, 214, 231, 61, 162, 34, 52, 250, 178, 136, 115, 115, 25, 168, 1, 129, 142, 238, 8, 184, 151, 234, 94, 126, 211, 175, 143, 100, 183, 238, 6, 244, 7, 41, 222, 1, 102, 64, 199, 99, 38, 198, 244, 145, 83, 255, 13, 29, 85, 127, 61, 140, 19, 92, 249, 76, 44, 191, 58, 248, 61, 44, 225, 154, 72, 215, 182, 148, 43, 16, 22, 29, 133, 37, 177, 95, 129, 176, 36, 129, 90, 244, 54, 43, 16, 22, 237, 225, 37, 177, 255, 27, 38, 183, 224, 140, 178, 26, 189, 95, 0, 0, 0, 0, 73, 69, 78, 68, 174, 66, 96, 130];

var imageData:NSData = NSData(bytes: bytes, length: bytes.count);
var image:UIImage = UIImage(data: imageData);
var imageView:UIImageView = UIImageView(image: image);
```

Answer (score 2):

I have my way to do it in Swift

```
if let serverBytesArray = serverAnswer as? NSArray {
    var bytes:[Byte] = []
    for serverByte in serverBytesArray {
        bytes.append(Byte(serverByte as UInt))
    }
    var data = NSData(bytes: bytes, length: bytes.count);
    let tmpDir = NSTemporaryDirectory()
    data.writeToFile(tmpDir.stringByAppendingPathComponent("test.pdf"), atomically: true)
}
```