# How do I convert a byte array to UIImage

Tags: ios, uiimage, byte

I have a webservice which sends me back an array of bytes like this:

```
<ax23:IMGBLOB>-119,80,78,71,13,10,26,10,0,0,0,13,73,72,68,82,0,0,0,100,0,0,0,106,8,3,0,0,0,125,54,4,22,0,0,0,51,80,76,84,69,0,0,0,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-73,-107,-30,-126,0,0,0,16,116,82,78,83,0,16,32,48,64,80,96,112,-128,-112,-96,-80,-64,-48,-32,-16,84,-32,-88,-56,0,0,2,126,73,68,65,84,120,-38,-19,90,65,-110,-124,32,12,4,68,64,69,-32,-1,-81,-35,-53,-78,-96,40,4,-79,-70,118,-86,-90,-113,51,106,-101,116,-120,33,-127,-3,43,72,101,-84,13,127,-80,-42,40,-7,42,-63,100,108,-72,-124,53,-45,75,38,-84,62,84,-32,-41,97,-125,-72,118,-95,9,-89,-7,0,-123,-56,-115,-88,-101,35,-98,90,-79,-122,14,-84,-113,-84,49,62,116,-63,-101,126,-71,-9,112,-58,-66,25,45,127,-95,-51,118,113,-127,-20,52,-29,124,-1,34,121,-31,78,-71,-100,-119,76,-113,-32,-5,-111,65,-117,-37,43,-11,-23,82,65,118,-107,63,40,42,91,-21,-24,-96,12,-47,101,-22,64,33,8,-122,31,104,20,-123,99,9,9,-106,104,-67,-80,-7,123,-79,38,-78,-73,114,51,35,99,118,29,44,-21,-45,-27,-59,-13,59,-87,-66,-14,-118,117,66,-91,120,89,104,-102,-69,7,57,124,114,20,-11,101,-118,119,-2,40,-37,-91,69,35,111,99,-60,-25,28,99,44,-2,46,46,-9,-100,99,-108,101,-81,-28,-85,-56,49,-50,98,-86,-126,56,-50,6,-64,93,41,75,-23,44,63,13,86,29,-2,-34,97,38,69,-33,32,-44,-83,-61,-72,-89,-26,4,122,102,-14,-68,-8,-93,16,100,80,-106,-14,-123,69,52,113,102,47,96,-114,79,19,-105,-122,88,-10,10,-74,43,83,-72,-49,-87,-57,33,-82,84,-47,45,-43,-71,-115,5,92,-97,-10,-102,37,-72,104,72,-43,126,111,120,-81,41,46,91,-20,-51,-16,-115,-9,-88,94,83,100,-15,-53,116,79,18,97,37,113,-35,23,-17,-19,99,30,-72,5,-79,-24,45,-77,-108,63,-77,-22,54,9,-67,-24,-43,39,-17,-104,40,123,-101,-124,94,-58,-120,83,2,-77,77,111,-79,112,-126,-99,-88,-2,-78,-57,39,24,2,73,-62,-62,-119,53,-5,49,-128,101,23,73,-16,21,9,-53,-57,-86,72,73,35,73,112,-110,17,-18,81,-71,93,59,-103,36,-63,-118,-74,40,38,-41,125,35,-112,-108,48,-68,-107,-118,109,78,98,-70,72,8,-27,-84,73,36,-55,119,68,18,-54,86,-79,-44,-102,16,92,44,84,-79,93,74,35,7,73,74,-97,1,72,66,-104,-21,36,60,102,-78,33,18,-53,10,8,8,9,-64,93,31,41,-4,90,13,97,-56,98,-124,-92,21,72,-126,28,77,-11,27,37,-43,67,62,90,-112,-49,47,-94,-112,24,40,-119,4,-71,36,-126,20,119,-112,50,21,89,112,-89,-51,68,-101,-60,78,-99,91,7,-56,38,8,-79,-99,-125,108,76,-79,91,-20,-9,-101,5,54,122,6,-46,-10,64,52,112,32,-83,40,68,83,13,-47,30,-124,52,58,17,45,91,68,-13,25,-46,70,71,12,4,16,-93,13,-64,-112,102,37,-113,-101,-74,-66,113,-45,22,18,7,98,112,6,29,1,-30,-121,-103,-8,-79,108,57,96,118,-75,1,-77,43,6,-52,-128,81,57,116,-24,-113,63,-66,-128,63,-120,-127,63,82,66,63,28,99,56,-2,-104,15,-2,-64,-46,-8,-47,-85,47,-66,-8,-30,-77,-16,3,-74,-58,-81,-89,-116,-22,56,-74,0,0,0,0,73,69,78,68,-82,66,96,-126,@@@@</ax23:IMGBLOB>
```

This array of bytes are used in Java for obtaining an image, I've been trying with several methods without success, I will post one of them below:

```
-(UIImageView *)convierteImagen: (NSMutableString *)cadenaImagen{
    //NSString to NSData (temporary)
    NSData *tempData = [cadenaImagen dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    //NSLog(@"datos crudos: %@", tempData);

    //2.NSData to Bytes
    const void  *bytes2 = [tempData bytes];
    int8_t      *bytes  = (int8_t*)bytes2;
    int         len     = tempData.length;

    cadenaImagen   = [[NSMutableString alloc]init];

    [cadenaImagen appendString:@"["];
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (i)  [cadenaImagen appendString:@","];
        [cadenaImagen appendFormat:@"%d", bytes[i]];
    }
    [cadenaImagen appendString:@"]"];

    //3.Bytes to NSData
    NSData *datos2 = [NSData dataWithBytes:bytes length:len];


    return [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageWithData:datos2]];
}
```

and the way I call this method is:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSMutableString *imagen = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@"-119,80,78,71,13,10,26,10,0,0,0,13,73,72,68,82,0,0,0,100,0,0,0,106,8,3,0,0,0,125,54,4,22,0,0,0,51,80,76,84,69,0,0,0,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-73,-107,-30,-126,0,0,0,16,116,82,78,83,0,16,32,48,64,80,96,112,-128,-112,-96,-80,-64,-48,-32,-16,84,-32,-88,-56,0,0,2,126,73,68,65,84,120,-38,-19,90,65,-110,-124,32,12,4,68,64,69,-32,-1,-81,-35,-53,-78,-96,40,4,-79,-70,118,-86,-90,-113,51,106,-101,116,-120,33,-127,-3,43,72,101,-84,13,127,-80,-42,40,-7,42,-63,100,108,-72,-124,53,-45,75,38,-84,62,84,-32,-41,97,-125,-72,118,-95,9,-89,-7,0,-123,-56,-115,-88,-101,35,-98,90,-79,-122,14,-84,-113,-84,49,62,116,-63,-101,126,-71,-9,112,-58,-66,25,45,127,-95,-51,118,113,-127,-20,52,-29,124,-1,34,121,-31,78,-71,-100,-119,76,-113,-32,-5,-111,65,-117,-37,43,-11,-23,82,65,118,-107,63,40,42,91,-21,-24,-96,12,-47,101,-22,64,33,8,-122,31,104,20,-123,99,9,9,-106,104,-67,-80,-7,123,-79,38,-78,-73,114,51,35,99,118,29,44,-21,-45,-27,-59,-13,59,-87,-66,-14,-118,117,66,-91,120,89,104,-102,-69,7,57,124,114,20,-11,101,-118,119,-2,40,-37,-91,69,35,111,99,-60,-25,28,99,44,-2,46,46,-9,-100,99,-108,101,-81,-28,-85,-56,49,-50,98,-86,-126,56,-50,6,-64,93,41,75,-23,44,63,13,86,29,-2,-34,97,38,69,-33,32,-44,-83,-61,-72,-89,-26,4,122,102,-14,-68,-8,-93,16,100,80,-106,-14,-123,69,52,113,102,47,96,-114,79,19,-105,-122,88,-10,10,-74,43,83,-72,-49,-87,-57,33,-82,84,-47,45,-43,-71,-115,5,92,-97,-10,-102,37,-72,104,72,-43,126,111,120,-81,41,46,91,-20,-51,-16,-115,-9,-88,94,83,100,-15,-53,116,79,18,97,37,113,-35,23,-17,-19,99,30,-72,5,-79,-24,45,-77,-108,63,-77,-22,54,9,-67,-24,-43,39,-17,-104,40,123,-101,-124,94,-58,-120,83,2,-77,77,111,-79,112,-126,-99,-88,-2,-78,-57,39,24,2,73,-62,-62,-119,53,-5,49,-128,101,23,73,-16,21,9,-53,-57,-86,72,73,35,73,112,-110,17,-18,81,-71,93,59,-103,36,-63,-118,-74,40,38,-41,125,35,-112,-108,48,-68,-107,-118,109,78,98,-70,72,8,-27,-84,73,36,-55,119,68,18,-54,86,-79,-44,-102,16,92,44,84,-79,93,74,35,7,73,74,-97,1,72,66,-104,-21,36,60,102,-78,33,18,-53,10,8,8,9,-64,93,31,41,-4,90,13,97,-56,98,-124,-92,21,72,-126,28,77,-11,27,37,-43,67,62,90,-112,-49,47,-94,-112,24,40,-119,4,-71,36,-126,20,119,-112,50,21,89,112,-89,-51,68,-101,-60,78,-99,91,7,-56,38,8,-79,-99,-125,108,76,-79,91,-20,-9,-101,5,54,122,6,-46,-10,64,52,112,32,-83,40,68,83,13,-47,30,-124,52,58,17,45,91,68,-13,25,-46,70,71,12,4,16,-93,13,-64,-112,102,37,-113,-101,-74,-66,113,-45,22,18,7,98,112,6,29,1,-30,-121,-103,-8,-79,108,57,96,118,-75,1,-77,43,6,-52,-128,81,57,116,-24,-113,63,-66,-128,63,-120,-127,63,82,66,63,28,99,56,-2,-104,15,-2,-64,-46,-8,-47,-85,47,-66,-8,-30,-77,-16,3,-74,-58,-81,-89,-116,-22,56,-74,0,0,0,0,73,69,78,68,-82,66,96,-126"];

    [self.view addSubview:[self convierteImagen:imagen]];
}
```

Any help I will appreciate :)

Comment: Check this similar answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11860830/byte-array-to-nsdata

Comment: both solutions (Nishant Tyagi and Jesus) are correct thank you two for your support!!! =D

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try this:

```
-(UIImageView *)convierteImagen: (NSMutableString *)cadenaImagen{

    NSArray *strings = [cadenaImagen componentsSeparatedByString:@","];

    unsigned c = strings.count;
    uint8_t *bytes = malloc(sizeof(*bytes) * c);

    unsigned i;
    for (i = 0; i < c; i++)
    {
        NSString *str = [strings objectAtIndex:i];
        int byte = [str intValue];
        bytes[i] = (uint8_t)byte;
    }

    NSData *datos = [NSData dataWithBytes:bytes length:c];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:datos];

    return [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:image];
}
```

on viewdidLoad is the same code you put:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSMutableString *imagen = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@"-119,80,78,71,13,10,26,10,0,0,0,13,73,72,68,82,0,0,0,100,0,0,0,106,8,3,0,0,0,125,54,4,22,0,0,0,51,80,76,84,69,0,0,0,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-73,-107,-30,-126,0,0,0,16,116,82,78,83,0,16,32,48,64,80,96,112,-128,-112,-96,-80,-64,-48,-32,-16,84,-32,-88,-56,0,0,2,126,73,68,65,84,120,-38,-19,90,65,-110,-124,32,12,4,68,64,69,-32,-1,-81,-35,-53,-78,-96,40,4,-79,-70,118,-86,-90,-113,51,106,-101,116,-120,33,-127,-3,43,72,101,-84,13,127,-80,-42,40,-7,42,-63,100,108,-72,-124,53,-45,75,38,-84,62,84,-32,-41,97,-125,-72,118,-95,9,-89,-7,0,-123,-56,-115,-88,-101,35,-98,90,-79,-122,14,-84,-113,-84,49,62,116,-63,-101,126,-71,-9,112,-58,-66,25,45,127,-95,-51,118,113,-127,-20,52,-29,124,-1,34,121,-31,78,-71,-100,-119,76,-113,-32,-5,-111,65,-117,-37,43,-11,-23,82,65,118,-107,63,40,42,91,-21,-24,-96,12,-47,101,-22,64,33,8,-122,31,104,20,-123,99,9,9,-106,104,-67,-80,-7,123,-79,38,-78,-73,114,51,35,99,118,29,44,-21,-45,-27,-59,-13,59,-87,-66,-14,-118,117,66,-91,120,89,104,-102,-69,7,57,124,114,20,-11,101,-118,119,-2,40,-37,-91,69,35,111,99,-60,-25,28,99,44,-2,46,46,-9,-100,99,-108,101,-81,-28,-85,-56,49,-50,98,-86,-126,56,-50,6,-64,93,41,75,-23,44,63,13,86,29,-2,-34,97,38,69,-33,32,-44,-83,-61,-72,-89,-26,4,122,102,-14,-68,-8,-93,16,100,80,-106,-14,-123,69,52,113,102,47,96,-114,79,19,-105,-122,88,-10,10,-74,43,83,-72,-49,-87,-57,33,-82,84,-47,45,-43,-71,-115,5,92,-97,-10,-102,37,-72,104,72,-43,126,111,120,-81,41,46,91,-20,-51,-16,-115,-9,-88,94,83,100,-15,-53,116,79,18,97,37,113,-35,23,-17,-19,99,30,-72,5,-79,-24,45,-77,-108,63,-77,-22,54,9,-67,-24,-43,39,-17,-104,40,123,-101,-124,94,-58,-120,83,2,-77,77,111,-79,112,-126,-99,-88,-2,-78,-57,39,24,2,73,-62,-62,-119,53,-5,49,-128,101,23,73,-16,21,9,-53,-57,-86,72,73,35,73,112,-110,17,-18,81,-71,93,59,-103,36,-63,-118,-74,40,38,-41,125,35,-112,-108,48,-68,-107,-118,109,78,98,-70,72,8,-27,-84,73,36,-55,119,68,18,-54,86,-79,-44,-102,16,92,44,84,-79,93,74,35,7,73,74,-97,1,72,66,-104,-21,36,60,102,-78,33,18,-53,10,8,8,9,-64,93,31,41,-4,90,13,97,-56,98,-124,-92,21,72,-126,28,77,-11,27,37,-43,67,62,90,-112,-49,47,-94,-112,24,40,-119,4,-71,36,-126,20,119,-112,50,21,89,112,-89,-51,68,-101,-60,78,-99,91,7,-56,38,8,-79,-99,-125,108,76,-79,91,-20,-9,-101,5,54,122,6,-46,-10,64,52,112,32,-83,40,68,83,13,-47,30,-124,52,58,17,45,91,68,-13,25,-46,70,71,12,4,16,-93,13,-64,-112,102,37,-113,-101,-74,-66,113,-45,22,18,7,98,112,6,29,1,-30,-121,-103,-8,-79,108,57,96,118,-75,1,-77,43,6,-52,-128,81,57,116,-24,-113,63,-66,-128,63,-120,-127,63,82,66,63,28,99,56,-2,-104,15,-2,-64,-46,-8,-47,-85,47,-66,-8,-30,-77,-16,3,-74,-58,-81,-89,-116,-22,56,-74,0,0,0,0,73,69,78,68,-82,66,96,-126"];

    [self.view addSubview:[self convierteImagen: imagen]];
}
```

this is what I got with your byte array:

[image: picture]

so I think this should solve your problem ;)

Comment: How can I enter byte array values directly from the JSON string? I tried this,but it isn't working for me:  "NSMutableString *imagen = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:[[JSON valueForKey:@"request"]valueForKey:@"logo" ]];         @Jesus
"

Comment: Any swift version available??