# Proper way to get the byte array from the JSON

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, uiimage, nsdata

I am trying to get the image from the byte array. I can only get the image if enter the byte  array values into the string directly as follows:

```
    NSMutableString *imagen = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@"-1,-40,-1,-32,0,16,74,70,73,70,0,1,0,1,0,96,0,96,0,0,-1,-2,0,31,76,69,65,68,32,84,101,99,104,110,111,108,111,103,105,101,115,32,73,110,99,46,32,86,49,46,48,49,0,-1,-37,0,-124,0,5,5,5,8,5,8,12,7,7,12,12,9,9,9,12,13,12,12,12,12,13,13,13,13,13,13,13,13,13,13,13,13,13,13,13,13,13,13];
```

//this way works fine

IF i try to get the byte array into string as follows,then I couldnt get the image:

```
    NSString *logo=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[JSON valueForKey:@"request"]valueForKey:@"logo" ]];

    NSMutableString *imagen = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:logo];

   //this way doesnt work out
```

I am following this link to get the thing done.[this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16744682/how-do-i-convert-a-byte-array-to-uiimage)

Could you please tell me whats the proper way to get byte array from JSON?

Comment: How is the image data encoded in the JSON since JSON does not support data? Base64 or something else?

Comment: I ddidnt encoded the image. It is done by another developer. I am updating my question. PLease look into it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not executable code, it is a method to use:

You get the JSON in `self.receivedData`

Convert it into an object with
`NSDictionary *jsonObject = NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:`

** Unknown how the image data is encoded in the JSON. If it is Base64 encoded:

Get the Base64image string with
`NSString *imageString = jsonObject[@"request"][@"logo"]`

Convert the Base64 string into data:
`NSData *imageData = [NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString: imageString  options:`

Get an image with
`UIImage *logoImage = [imageData  imageWithData]`

All in all you have way to  much code that accomplished nothing and converting the image data to an `NSString` is incorrect.

Converting to a string and then back to data accomplishes nothing.

Answer (score 0):

This code seems confused? The link you posted has string encodings which contain negative numbers. You parse these as signed but then assign them to an array of unsigned uint8_t using `bytes[i] = (uint8_t)byte;`.

I think you need to post the string encoding format and an example?