# Response byte array from json

Tags: ios, json, swift, xcode, alamofire

How can I response byte array from the server and convert it to image. This my code
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LIpmW.jpg)

```
Alamofire.request(mainUrl, method:.post , parameters: paramstring , encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON { response in
        if let data = response.data
        {
            switch response.result
            {
            case.failure(let error):
            print(error)
            case.success(let value):
                let json = JSON(value)
                guard let dataarr = json["my_profile"].arrayObject as? [String] else {return}
                let image = dataarr[0]
                let mydata = image.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)! as NSData
                print(mydata)
                let mybase64 = mydata.base64EncodedData(options: NSData.Base64EncodingOptions.endLineWithLineFeed)
                print(mybase64)
                self.MainView.avatarImageView.image = UIImage(data: mybase64)

            }
        }
```

as you can see , its not byte array , and it continue to 1000 rows
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LIpmW.jpg)

Comment: Could you paste the json data that you recieve?

Comment: This is a small part of json , as you can see it's not byte array "my_profile": [ "\\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 –

Comment: Could you try this code since its a partial data https://stackoverflow.com/a/38313261/2323806

Comment: I tried , but it couldn't worked

Comment: here I have one problem , data which on the server not same with data I response , I try to convert responses string to byte array, but I got same result , so strange :/

Comment: If could paste your server response or attach a screenshot with your question, that would help

Comment: add your server response

Comment: added to description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data is not Base64-encoded. It's hex encoded. You need to hex-decode it, not use `base64EncodedData`.

First, you need to drop the first two characters (`\x`):

```
let hex = dataarr[0].dropFirst(2)
```

Then you need a method to convert hex to Data. There are many ways. Here's one:

```
extension Data {
    init?<S: StringProtocol>(hexString: S) {
        guard hexString.count % 2 == 0 else { return nil }  // Must be even number of letters

        var bytes: [UInt8] = []

        var index = hexString.startIndex
        while index != hexString.endIndex {
            let secondIndex = hexString.index(after: index)
            let hexValue = hexString[index...secondIndex]
            guard let byte = UInt8(hexValue, radix: 16) else { return nil } // Unexpected character
            bytes.append(byte)
            index = hexString.index(after: secondIndex)
        }
        self.init(bytes)
    }
}
```

With that, decode it:

```
if let data = Data(hexString: hex),
   let image = UIImage(data: data) {
       // ... use image
}
```

Comment: YOOOO MAN YOU ARE MY HERO , THANK YOU VERY MUCH , I HARD WORKED WITH THIS PROBLEM 3 DAYS

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code

```
let mydata = image.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)! as NSData
print(mydata)
let mybase64 = mydata.base64EncodedData(options: NSData.Base64EncodingOptions.endLineWithLineFeed)
print(mybase64)
self.MainView.avatarImageView.image = UIImage(data: mybase64)
```

With

```
if let mydata : Data = Data(base64Encoded: image, options: .ignoreUnknownCharacters) {
   DispatchQueue.main.async {
       self.MainView.avatarImageView.image = UIImage(data: mydata)
    }

}
```

Comment: not working ( maybe I have problem with json response , can you check it ?

Comment: @ЧингизКуандык Is your `if let mydata : Data =` condition gets true means your print data is showing anything ?

Comment: @ЧингизКуандык Try it in main queue

Comment: I add image of my project in description

Comment: @ЧингизКуандык print(myData) is executing ?