# How can I convert byte array to base64 string in swift?

Tags: ios, json, swift, uiimageview, nsdate

When I get my JSON back from my API this is how it looks

```
{
  data:[
     100,
     80,
     105,
     99,
     etc
  ]

}
```

How do I take this array and turn it back into a base64 string, then NSData and finally UIImage.
Here is what I have thus far.

```
let byteArray = todo["image"]["data"].arrayObject
var data = NSData(bytes: byteArray!, length: byteArray!.count)
var image = UIImage(data: data)
```

When printing the data it prints fine but returns nil for image.

Comment: Is that a real sample of the JSON from your API?

Comment: it has a few fields before it but all I need to figure out is how to convert the data array of bytes to NSData

Comment: Assuming that these are decimal values, this does not look like base64 data.

Comment: This is how my blob returns the data

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried iterating throug the array and building a string from its  elements, the use base64 encoding/decoding api to get back from string to NSData? Something like that(I'm writing from iPad so I can't check).

```
var encodedString=""
for smallString in byteArray {
   encodedString += String(smallString)
}
let data = NSData(base64EncodedString: base64Encoded, options: NSDataBase64DecodingOptions.IgnoreUnknownCharacters)
var image = UIImage(data: data)
```

Comment: What do you mean by encoded string. All I have is a data array with bytes. That is what my API returns to me

Comment: Isn't the content of your array a string representation of the base 64 encode image?

Comment: No my API stores the encoded base 64 string as a BLOB but blobs return the data as a byte array

Comment: For instance this is a piece of image base64 encoded: iVBORw0KGgoAA and this is a C byte array byte[] bytes = { 3, 10, 8, 25 }; check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11860830/byte-array-to-nsdata

Answer (score 0):

```
    let byteArray = todo["image"]["data"].arrayObject         
    let string = String(bytes: byteArray, encoding: .utf8)
    let encodedImageData = string
    let imageData = NSData(base64Encoded: encodedImageData!)
    let image = UIImage(data: imageData! as Data)
```