# How to convert java byte array to swift nsdata?

Tags: java, json, uiimageview, swift2

I get json response from java rest webservice it contains an image binary data and I can't convert this binary data and show the image in UIImageView

I try this in swift but it returns nil

```
let image = [Int]()  
let uintArray = intArray.map { UInt(bitPattern: $0) }
let dataImage = NSData(bytes: uintArray, length: uintArray.count)
```

Comment: How are you sending binary data in JSON ?

Comment: I get image as array of byte from json

Comment: JSON is a string format, it doesn't support binary data. Are you converting data to base64 or something ?

Comment: I can deserialize json and get this array like [-37, 100, -16, -10, -39, 31 ,etc]

Comment: I still don't get it, but you probably can try deserializing the data on the server itself to produce the image file. That will make sure that response was produced correctly.

Comment: I am sure about the response because android app can load the image but in ios I can convert this array to nsdata

Comment: I think this is what you're looking for http://stackoverflow.com/a/11860928/5343269

Comment: thanks for the link but I need swift code

Comment: i have same issue...have you found any solution?

Comment: let str1 = cadenaImagen.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("[", withString: "")
        let str2 = str1.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("]", withString: "")
        let str = str2.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: "")        
        var strings = str.componentsSeparatedByString(",")
        var bytes = [UInt8]()
        for i in 0...strings.count-1 {
            if let signedByte = Int8(strings[i]) {
                bytes.append(UInt8(bitPattern: signedByte))
            } 
        }
        let datos: NSData = NSData(bytes: bytes, length: bytes.count)

Comment: I fixed it with this part of code i hope it can help u :)